# How to write vba code in Access by using another vba access code?

Tags: ms-access

I have module to get the mac address, now i need way to save it in vba code like

once you run the data for first time in your pc he will call your mac address like that XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

now I need way to automatically  write this code in module

```
dim PcMacAdd as string 
set PcMAcadd = XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
```

Comment: What will you do then with this MAC by writing to module? Rather use function to get MAC then use that function where you need. You may then save it to table, display in a form or report, export to external file like excel, txt or print to paper.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your function returns, but if you use the functions from [VBA.MacAddress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.MacAddress), you can do like this:

```vb
Dim PcMacAdd As String 

PcMAcadd = FormatMacAddress(MacAddressLocal, ipMacDash)
```

Full documentation is [MAC addresses in Access and Excel](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33827/MAC-addresses-in-Access-and-Excel.html?preview=hKzA%2BRnLzj4%3D).

Comment: OH THANKS bro but i do not need this what i need
to secure my application if i send you a copy i need he get your mac address after first time you open it and take this mac and record it in vba code to check in every time you open it your application if the mac has changed that is means new pc
i do not want to save it on table cuz its easy to find the table and change the mac

Comment: What do you need, please?